# Does Windows 7 natively support MKV?

Tags: windows-7, matroska

After reading that it does and doesn't on various websites, I tried it myself. The only thing that played was the audio - no video. However, I had already installed and uninstalled CCCP and k-lite in past, so this may have affected the results. Does Windows 7 natively support MKV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Windows does not support the MKV video container format as the splitter required to split the parts in the .mkv file (video, audio, subtitles etc.) is not pre-installed. 
Thus, even if Windows supports the codecs for the video, a splitter would still be required.

Answer (score 3):

MKV is a container for audio and video streams encoded with a certain codec. We would need to be looking at the actual codecs inside the mkv file you have to really know if its native.

However, I highly doubt it will be native to Windows just because in the past I've always needed to install VLC to get anything practical to play.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not, you need third party tools to help you, for example, you can use the VLC player, KMPlayer, easy DVD player to deal with MKV files on your Windows 7 platform computer

Comment: Hi @Jessica, welcome to Superuser! You could improve your answer with links to the different players.